# Parameter Meaning of CVXOPT solvers. Options['show_progress']

Tags: python, optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, cvxopt

My Solver has been failing starting this week, which did run pretty well in the past. The inputs and set up are all the same but not sure why it doesn't solve now. Here is the output of interim process. That "dres" and "pres" parameters just catch my eyes. Anyone know what does this mean?

I have tried everything. The input are exactly the same, the codes are source-controlled but still feel so confused why this is failing. The cvxopt version never changes as well.

[image]